# calculating urban population percentage of total population for each district in PostgreSql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table namely settlement consist of 3 columns and 5437 rows.
**The first column has 8 group(A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H) and the second one has '6' group(City,Town,Village,Island,Suburb,Hamlet)**

My table is as following...

```
ID     district_name              Cluster         Population    

1003        A                    village            1543          
1002        B                    town               63437   
1003        C                    village            1698    
1002        D                    town               11785   
1040        E                    hamlet             100 
2034        F                    hamlet             190 
4003        G                    city               207561  
4243        H                    Suburb             682 
674         D                    Island             718 
1012        A                    village            1566
1040        F                    hamlet             200
1020        D                    town               11881
4055        D                    city               208763
```

**I want to calculate the percentage of population for each district base on the following condition;**

```
total population in each district/sum(population)*100
where cluster='city' or cluster='town'
```

`A practical example of my desire outpout can be as follows`,

```
district_name  Population_total(City+Town+island) Urban_Percentage(Town_City)


     D                233147                      99.69(232429/233147 * 100)
```

Comment: "the result is not correct' provides very little information to help.  What are the results?  Sample data?  Desired results?

Comment: can you show us some sample data and expected result?

Comment: we cant copy/paste from images. Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) you can use this tool https://senseful.github.io/text-table/

Comment: Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Comment: Check for example this question (schema, sample data, expected output):  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49257687/mysql-returning-highest-ranked-event-for-a-user

Comment: Dear @JuanCarlosOropeza I have modified my question and would be thankful if you could answer.

Comment: So what would be the expected result with that data?

Comment: I want the percentage of population who only live in city and town for each district

Comment: I need the numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/577ac/5)**

```
WITH  district as (         
     SELECT district_name, 
            sum("Population") as district_total
     FROM residentioal 
     where "Cluster"='city' or "Cluster"='town'
     GROUP BY district_name
), whole_total as (
     SELECT district_name, sum("Population") as total
     FROM residentioal 
     GROUP BY district_name
 )
SELECT d.district_name, 
       total as whole_total,
       district_total as city_town_total,        
       district_total * 100.0 / total as PP
FROM district d
JOIN whole_total  w
  ON d.district_name = w.district_name
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| district_name | whole_total | city_town_total |                pp |
|---------------|-------------|-----------------|-------------------|
|             D |      233147 |          232429 | 99.69203978605772 |
|             B |       63437 |           63437 |               100 |
|             G |      207561 |          207561 |               100 |
```

**EDIT:**

**[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/577ac/9)**

You actually can do it with a single query:

```
SELECT   district_name,
         sum("Population") as total,
         sum(CASE WHEN "Cluster" IN ('city', 'town') 
                  THEN "Population"
                  ELSE 0
             END ) as district_total,
         sum(CASE WHEN "Cluster" IN ('city', 'town') 
                  THEN "Population"
                  ELSE 0
             END )  * 100.0 / sum("Population") as PP
FROM residentioal
GROUP BY district_name;
```

Comment: please try again

Comment: Check new version.

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer. I actually, want the ' city_tow_total' column to be the sum of all cluster(city+town+hamlet+village+island+suburb per district) not only (city and town). Therefore, the formula is; sum of population in town and city / sum of all population in all cluster *100 
NOTE : FOR EACH DISTRICT WE HAVE DIFFERENT NUMBER OF TOTAL POPULATION. I would be appreciate if you could answer me. sorry, my explanation was not good enough

Comment: I told you I need the numbers. Otherwise is a guessing game and will waste my time trying to guess what you need :(

Comment: dear @Juan Carlos Oropeza I add a new edit as a desire output in a table format. This is the only thing left to clear :)
Hope I explained  precisely

Comment: Check  now, this return the result you post.

Comment: Thanks @Juan Finally we got it.  
That was the correct answer which I was looking for.

Comment: no problem, just remember next time you make a question post sample data and require output from start, that make thing easier