# MySQL Returning highest ranked event for a user

Tags: mysql, sql, select, rank

I currently use the following query to get the details of every user.

```
SELECT u.*, sums.total_votes, sums.no_of_events
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT
    us.user_uid,
    count(ev.event_vote_id) AS total_votes 
    count(distinct ue.event_uid) AS no_of_events
  FROM user_event ue
  LEFT JOIN event_vote ev
  ON ev.event_uid = ue.event_uid
  GROUP BY ue.user_uid
) sums ON sums.user_uid = u.user_uid
```

However, I wish to also return the rank of their highest voted event (out of all events - not just their own).

**USER**

```
|  USER_UID  |  FIRSTNAME  |  LASTNAME  | 
       1         bob          smith
       2         rob          smithies 
       3         john         clark
```

**EVENT**

```
| GUID | NAME |  
  101   event1
  102   event2
  103   event3
```

**USER_EVENT**

```
| USER_EVENT_ID | USER_UID | EVENT_UID | 
       1001           1         101
       1002           2         102
       1003           1         103
```

**EVENT_VOTE**

```
| EVENT_VOTE_ID | USER_UID | EVENT_UID | 
       2001            2       101       
       2002            3       101
       2003            2       103
```

**Expected Result**

```
user_uid: 1
firstname: bob
lastname: smith
votes: 3        // 2 for 101, 1 for 103.
no_of_events: 2
bestRank: 1 (1st)    // ranked 1st and 2nd but 1st is higher.

user_uid: 2
firstname: rob
lastname: smithies
votes: 0      
no_of_events: 1
bestRank: 3 (3rd)
```

Comment: In this case there is a tie for the 2nd highest. You want both be 2nd and then the 4th higher be 3rd? or 4th? so rank or dense_rank?

Comment: what happen if one user have a tie between two event, which one you show?

Comment: I would prefer both 2nd but if it is easier - for now, a different rank is OK but maybe ordered by guid after votes DESC? To always return the same result if the query is run.

Comment: This is my first attempt. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/04e57/13  still need to work some things

Comment: Looks good, it just needs to return the best rn for each user now.

Comment: Ok, I solve the ties. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0c781f/3, you can see, there is a tie between user 1 and 2, and also a tie with the last two of user 2

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. However if you look at my expected results, it is different to your results. With this dense result I want to return the best ranking from a user (bestRank).

Comment: I know. I'm just checking if the rank is working for your request.  Also I have to add more events to test border cases. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0c781f/11  rn is normal rank, dense is dense rank. I think you want dense?

Comment: Oh ok. Yeah the rank is working fine now, thank you.

Comment: Yes it is dense rank I require.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query has 3 parts

1. Your Original query to calculate total events for each users
2. Ranking all events for most votes.
3. Filtering what events has the best ranking

In the demo you can also see three query so you can debug the partial results.

Current output also is a partial result, to get your desire result you need add

```
WHERE R.event_uid IS NULL
```

**[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0c781f/31)**

**[Final version](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0c781f/33)**

```
SELECT *
FROM (  SELECT u.*, sums.total_votes, sums.no_of_events
        FROM user u
        JOIN ( SELECT ue.user_uid,
                      count(ev.event_vote_id) AS total_votes, 
                      count(distinct ue.event_uid) AS no_of_events
               FROM user_event ue
               LEFT JOIN event_vote ev
                 ON ev.event_uid = ue.event_uid
               GROUP BY ue.user_uid
             ) as sums
          ON u.user_uid  = sums.user_uid 
     ) as U
JOIN (  SELECT T.*,
               @rank := @rank + 1 as rn,
               @dense := if (@votes = votes,
                             @dense,
                             if(@votes := votes, @rank, @rank)
                            ) as dense
        FROM (
              SELECT 
                     e.guid as event_uid,
                     ue.user_uid, 
                     count(ev.event_uid) AS votes             
              FROM event e
              JOIN user_event ue
                ON e.guid = ue.event_uid
              LEFT JOIN event_vote ev
                ON ev.event_uid = ue.event_uid      
              GROUP BY e.GUID, ue.user_uid
              ORDER BY count(ue.event_uid) DESC
             ) as T
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rank := 0, @dense := 0, @votes := 0 ) as vars
        ORDER BY votes desc, event_uid
)  as Q
ON U.user_uid = Q.user_uid
LEFT JOIN (  SELECT T.*,
               @rank2 := @rank2 + 1 as rn,
               @dense2 := if (@votes2 = votes,
                             @dense2,
                             if(@votes2 := votes, @rank2, @rank2)
                            ) as dense
        FROM (
              SELECT 
                     e.guid as event_uid,
                     ue.user_uid, 
                     count(ev.event_uid) AS votes             
              FROM event e
              JOIN user_event ue
                ON e.guid = ue.event_uid
              LEFT JOIN event_vote ev
                ON ev.event_uid = ue.event_uid      
              GROUP BY e.GUID, ue.user_uid
              ORDER BY count(ue.event_uid) DESC
             ) as T
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rank2 := 0, @dense2 := 0, @votes2 := 0 ) as vars
        ORDER BY votes desc, event_uid
)  as R
ON  Q.user_uid = R.user_uid
AND Q.rn > R.rn
-- WHERE  R.event_uid IS NULL
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| USER_UID | FIRSTNAME | LASTNAME | total_votes | no_of_events | event_uid | user_uid | votes | rn | dense | event_uid | user_uid |  votes |     rn |  dense |
|----------|-----------|----------|-------------|--------------|-----------|----------|-------|----|-------|-----------|----------|--------|--------|--------|
|        1 |       bob |    smith |           3 |            2 |       101 |        1 |     2 |  1 |     1 |    (null) |   (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |
|        1 |       bob |    smith |           3 |            2 |       103 |        1 |     1 |  3 |     2 |       101 |        1 |      2 |      1 |      1 |
|        2 |       rob | smithies |           1 |            3 |       102 |        2 |     1 |  2 |     2 |    (null) |   (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |
|        2 |       rob | smithies |           1 |            3 |       104 |        2 |     0 |  4 |     4 |       102 |        2 |      1 |      2 |      2 |
|        2 |       rob | smithies |           1 |            3 |       105 |        2 |     0 |  5 |     4 |       102 |        2 |      1 |      2 |      2 |
|        2 |       rob | smithies |           1 |            3 |       105 |        2 |     0 |  5 |     4 |       104 |        2 |      0 |      4 |      4 |
```

Comment: I only wish to return one record for each user containing their best rank along with the data I already store.

Comment: Read my comment, you need add a `WHERE` and there isnt date on your data. I already rank the event for votes and for lower id

Comment: Sorry you must of just posted that. Where do I add the WHERE clause please?

Comment: Check the code, I put it at the end as comment. And include another link to just the final version. (Need select relevant columns). But If you cant add a WHERE do you think can handle that code? Also remember I add additional events to test border cases.

Comment: Ok thanks, it should be fine. However this only returns users that have events?

Comment: I would like to be able to return uid, firstname, last name and the rest null if the user has no events. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, You are  right, need change those JOIN for LEFT JOIN, but i wont fix that.

Comment: I have added the LEFT joins now and it displays all users successfully. Thanks again.

Comment: remember upvote and accept the answer if help you solve your problem.